# Could not automatically start jboss via Cargo using Ant?

Tags: xml, ant, build-automation, cargo

Am kind of stuck in trying to start JBoss automatically from Ant script with the help of Cargo open source project. Am getting this error shown underneath. Many Thanks!

### taskdef:

```
    <taskdef resource="cargo.tasks">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${cargo.core.jar}"/>
            <pathelement location="${cargo.ant.jar}"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

### Jar Used:

```
 cargo-core-uberjar-1.2.1.jar
 cargo-ant-1.2.1.jar
```

### Ant target:

```
<!-- Start JBoss -->
<target name="startJboss" depends="prepare">
    <cargo id="mycontainerid" containerId="jboss51x" home="C:/opt/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/bin" action="start" wait="false" />
</target>
```

### Output Error:

```
Buildfile: D:\opt\trunk\build.xml
startJboss:

BUILD FAILED
D:\opt\trunk\build.xml:51: Could not create type cargo due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/discovery/resource/ClassLoaders

Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JBoss 4.0.5.GA, shouldn't you be using a matching value for `containerId` instead of `jboss51x`? (I have not used Cargo in a while, so I may be wrong about this)

The [Cargo - Ant support page](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Ant+support) says *Some additional dependencies might also be required for the ANT task. Please see the Installation page for details.*; when I go to the [Installation](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Installation), it tells me that you need to satisfy Cargo's base dependencies, which include Commons Discovery (which, your error message tells me, is missing) and Commons Logging. Add these JARs to the classpath for your `taskdef` and give it another shot.